# Use a regex for matching the value of an attribute parsing with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Hi from the clumsyland,

I'm trying to parse a forum. More specifically, the threads' names.

the threads are offered by the forum engine (vbulletin) as this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=555555" id="thread_title_555555">NAME OF THE TITLE</a>
```

Using python and beautifulsoup, I have obtain successes with other fields. However, I'm not able to parse "id" attribute using a regex. I need that these lines of the parser find every "a" element with a six-figure id and get the text from it

something like this

```
for elements in soup.findAll("a"):
    if re.match("thread_title_", element['id']) is not None:
        print element.text
```

or in pseudopython:

```
for elements in soup.finAll("a", {"id": "thread_title_".*}):
    print element.text
```

I tried dozens of variations, for no avail. What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of beautifulsoup, you can use lxml that supports xpath queries. With XPath you can select attributes that contain or start with a specific substring. (you need a tutorial)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have pending to review lxml. However, I'm a little bit proficient (not enough as you can see) with beautifulsoup. I wanted to make this part of the parser compatible with the rest of it

Comment: Please show the rest of your code

Comment: hi there - thansk Juan Luis,  i am trying to to this very similar to you here:  in a vbulletin find the tags metaData = soup.find_all: I'm trying to gather discussion and export it as a csv file, with rows such as "thread title", "user", and "post", where the latter is the actual forum post from an individual. `
# likewise the post data is stored
’# under <dd ...>
postData = soup.find_all("dd")

# define where we will store info
titles = []
authors = []
times = []
posts = []

’

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can match the id with a regex in the call to `findAll()`...

```
for element in soup.findAll("a", id=re.compile("^thread_title_")):
    print element.text
```

Comment: Thanks @shammel-lee!

I would like to make you 2 questions: (1) when I used findAll, attribute had to be between quotes. Why id is without quotes? How BS recognise it?

(2) re.compile generates a pattern object. If the condition expressed in such object is not None, then the loop condition applies and its commands are executed. Am I right? Thanks again!

Comment: hi there - thansk , i am trying to to this very similar to you here: in a vbulletin find the tags metaData = soup.find_all: I'm trying to gather discussion and export it as a csv file, with rows such as "thread title", "user", and "post", where the latter is the actual forum post from an individual. ` # likewise the post data is stored ’# under <dd ...> postData = soup.find_all("dd") # define where we will store info titles = [] authors = [] times = [] posts = [] ’

Comment: How would the syntax be for an aria attribute? namely `aria-label` ? I am trying to get spans with aria-label matching a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`\D*(\d{6})`

Does that not match what you want?  If not, what else have you tried?

EDITED: If the thread titles can include digits the above will not match, so consider using the regex `\w*(\d{6})`

The difference is `\D` matches all non-digits while `\w` matches any letter, digit or underscore.

Comment: Excuse my silly question: where can I put that Regex? I guess that in my pseudo python example I cannot write directly your expression

Comment: @downshift I think rather it would be `for title in soup.find_all("a", {"id": re.compile("\D*(\d{6})")}): print title.text` as I assume the "thread_title" is a generic term not meant to be matched every time but rather replaced by the individual title, which would be matched by the `\D*`.

Comment: @MatthewStevenson, sound good, I'll let you address OP's questions. thanks!

Comment: @downshift, now that I re-read the question you might have been right.  Will see what OP thinks.

Comment: Thanks you all. I wonder why "id" works in it, while id without quotes also works in @shammel-lee answer

Comment: I think it's the difference between `id=` and `"id":` but that's likely a python thing not a regex thing.